# Divs display in fiddle but not when i debug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

Currently I am working on a card voting system. I can get it to work properly in a jsfiddle but when i use microsoft visual studious and debug it, the cards do not display.

Here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/grahamwalsh/6RnXM/

and here is my code

Voting (Html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <title>Voting</title>
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.js"></script>
 <script src="Voting.js"></script>
 <script src="Voting.css"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div data-bind="foreach: items">
    <div class="profile" data-bind="text: name, click: $parent.clicked, enable: active,   css:{highlight: active()}"></div>
  </div>

 <hr>
 <h2>Selected Card</h2>
 <div data-bind="foreach: selectedItems">
    <div data-bind="text: name"></div>
 </div>
 <input type="button" data-bind="click: save" value="Save">
</body>
</html>
```

Voting (CSS)

```
body {.profile {
width: 50px;
height: 80px;
color: black;
background-color:silver;
border: 1px solid black;
float: left;
line-height:80px;
text-align: center;    
margin: 2px;
}
.highlight {
background: yellow !important;
border:1px solid #000;
color: black;
}
}


function Card(number) {
this.active = ko.observable(false);
this.name = ko.observable(number);
}

var model = function () {
var cards = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 20, 40, 100];
for (var i = 0 ; i < cards.length ; i++)
    cards[i] = new Card(cards[i]);
var items = ko.observableArray(cards)
var selectedItems = ko.computed(function () {
    return _.filter(items(), function (item) {
        return item.active();
    });
})

var clicked = function (item) {
    items().forEach(function (item) { item.active(false) });
    item.active(!this.active());
};

var save = function () {
    alert("sending items \n" + ko.toJSON(selectedItems()));
}

return {
    items: items,
    selectedItems: selectedItems,
    save: save,
    clicked: clicked
}
}



ko.applyBindings(model);
```

Voting (Js)

```
  function Card(number) {
this.active = ko.observable(false);
this.name = ko.observable(number);
 }

var model = function () {
var cards = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 20, 40, 100];
for (var i = 0 ; i < cards.length ; i++)
    cards[i] = new Card(cards[i]);
var items = ko.observableArray(cards)
var selectedItems = ko.computed(function () {
    return _.filter(items(), function (item) {
        return item.active();
    });
})

var clicked = function (item) {
    items().forEach(function (item) { item.active(false) });
    item.active(!this.active());
};

var save = function () {
    alert("sending items \n" + ko.toJSON(selectedItems()));
}

return {
    items: items,
    selectedItems: selectedItems,
    save: save,
    clicked: clicked
}
}



  ko.applyBindings(model);
```

Comment: Press F12. Go to Console and let us know if you are seeing any error in your console

Comment: im getting 
Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Comment: in which file? You must be seeing the file name there right? Can you please let us know that?

Comment: first error is js and second is css

Comment: Not sure which JS file it is. But do you think we can write function Card(number) { .......... in a CSS file?